# ESC to convert AC to DC?

Tags: rectifier, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm starting a project where I want to use a BLDC motor as a generator. I understand that BLDC's need an ESC to be controlled. Essentially an ESC converts DC power into AC and provides the necessary timing to trigger the different phases of the motor. I was wondering, could an ESC be used to do the opposite? That is, convert AC into DC? Would this be correct? If not, could someone explain why and suggest a better way of achieving this? If I would take a guest, I need some kind of three-phase rectifier. I just want to understand why I can't use an ESC to achieve the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: No. An analogy: can a camera be used as a display? No. Can two resistors in series, which can divide a voltage be used to multiply it? No. Somethings are not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

No, an ESC cannot be used to convert AC into DC. An ESC is an active circuit, and by design is a DC-powered switching controller. It's simply the wrong flavour of circuit.

However, you have nearly answered your own question. Yes, you need a [three-phase rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Three-phase_bridge_rectifier).

Comment: Kind of suspected this. I was just looking for a correct way of explaining why it can't be used for it. Thanks a bunch!